# Using cometd in dropwizard

Tags: java, cometd, dropwizard

I'm trying to use cometd as a servlet to dropwizard but BayeuxServer doesn't seem to get injected in my service. I'm adding my two servlets as so (note, I'm not using `web.xml` so I'm defining the params myself):

```
cometdConfig.put("services", MyService.class.getCanonicalName());

System.out.print("OrderService name: " + MyService.class.getCanonicalName());

environment.addServlet(AnnotationCometdServlet.class, "/cometd/*").addInitParams(cometdConfig).setInitOrder(1);
environment.addServlet(new MyServiceServlet(), "/orders/*").setInitOrder(2);
```

And my service (this is where my code fails):

```
public class MyService
implements MyWatcher.Listener
{
   @Inject
   private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;
   @Session
   private LocalSession sender;

   private final String _channelName;

   private ServerChannel _channel = null;

   public OrderService() {
      _channelName = "/cometd/";
      initChannel();
   }

   private void initChannel() {
      // I get an NPE here
      bayeuxServer.createIfAbsent(_channelName, new ConfigurableServerChannel.Initializer() {
        @Override
        public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
           // ...
        }
      });
    _channel = bayeuxServer.getChannel(_channelName);
   }
}
```

I have also tried creating my own instance of the BayeuxServer but then that leads to a separate NPE in `BayeuxServerImpl.freeze();`

Anyone know how to properly use cometd with dropwizard?

Comment: Don't use `Class.getCanonicalName()` as I think it will break classloading of inner classes. Use `Class.getName()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to inject the `BayeuxServer` instance, CometD must have the instance of the service to inject to, in this case an instance of your class `MyService`.

Unfortunately, from the constructor (which I think you misnamed above, calling it `OrderService`) you are calling the `initChannel()` method, which tries to use the `BayeuxServer` field which is not yet injected because the constructor is still executing.

The solution is to defer your channel initialization to a different method annotated with `@PostConstruct`:

```java
public class MyService
{
    @Inject
    private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;
    @Session
    private LocalSession sender;
    private final String _channelName;
    private ServerChannel _channel;

    public MyService() 
    {
        _channelName = "/cometd/";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void initChannel() 
    {
        _channel = bayeuxServer.createChannelIfAbsent(_channelName).getReference();
    }
}
```

The CometD API used is from CometD 2.7.0, which I recommend to use if you are on older CometD versions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using `@PostConstruct` but I'm still getting the NPE. When I check, `bayeuxServer` is still null, although it is now getting called later.

Comment: One thing I caught that I missed was not annotating my service with `@Service`. I tried it again without `@PostConstruct` and it still failed, so I would've needed it anyway. Thanks a lot!