# Using CometD in custom Ant Listener

Tags: cometd

I'm trying to hook up a custom Ant listener to CometD, but I get an NPE where I expect a channel handle. Here's a code snippet:

```
@Service
public class CometListener implements BuildListener {
    @Inject
    private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;
    @Session
    private LocalSession sender;

    private String _channelName;

    private ServerChannel _channel = null;

    public CometListener() {
        _channelName = "/my/test";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void initChannel() {
        _channel = bayeuxServer.createChannelIfAbsent(_channelName).getReference();
    }

    public final void buildFinished(final BuildEvent finish) {

        // Convert the Update business object to a CometD-friendly format
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>(4);
        data.put("status", 1);
        _channel.publish(sender, data);
        finish.getProject().log("buildFinished() called.", Project.MSG_ERR);
    }
}
```

I took [Using cometd in dropwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154457/using-cometd-in-dropwizard) as an example, but the proposed answer didn't fix the problem there.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Nevermind, I need a Bayeux client here, not a server

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I need a Bayeux client here, not a server.